# Set default value of Article Start Date to [Today] with CSOM

Tags: powershell, column, csom, date-time, default-value

I'm struggeling with setting the default value of `ArticleStartDate` date-time column using PowerShell and CSOM.

Bakground: I have a content type, used by a page layout, inheriting from `Article Page` and hence inherits the `ArticleStartDate` field.

What I want to achieve is setting the default date of this column to `[Today]`, globally, or only on one pages list (it really doesn't matter on what level the default values is set).

I have tried numerous variants like

```
$ctx = Get-SPOContext
$list = Get-SPOList -Identity "Pages"
$ctx.Load($list.Fields)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$articleDateField = $list.Fields | where {$_.InternalName -eq "ArticleStartDate" }
$articleDateField = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod("CastTo").MakeGenericMethod([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldDateTime]).Invoke($ctx, $articleDateField)
$articleDateField.DefaultValue = "[Today]";
$articleDateField.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Or the simpler

```
$ctx = Get-SPOContext
$list = Get-SPOList -Identity "Pages"
$ctx.Load($list.Fields)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$articleDateField = $list.Fields | where {$_.InternalName -eq "ArticleStartDate" }  
$articleDateField.DefaultValue = "[Today]";
$articleDateField.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

In neither of the cases I am getting any error messages, but when I retrieve the field again, the default value is not set.

I have noticed that the field is marked as `Sealed=TRUE` on site level, is this the problem? And if so, can we change that using CSOM or am I stuck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible for ArticleStartDate on O365 but involves modifying the SchemaXml (which isn't the nicest solution I appreciate, but needs must). Note that the below code snippet is in C# but obviously PowerShell is still using CSOM so should be easy to convert

```
private void DefaultArticleDate(ClientContext clientContext)
{
   string todaysDate = "=[Today]";
   string defaultFormula = "><DefaultFormula>{0}</DefaultFormula></Field>";
   Field article = clientContext.Web.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("ArticleStartDate");
   clientContext.Load(article);
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

   /*Appreciate replacing the XML isnt the nicest way to do this but it works, cant remember if changing Sealed matters here so you can potentially remove this part and just leave in the second .Replace() call*/
   article.SchemaXml = article.SchemaXml.Replace("Sealed=\"TRUE\"", "Sealed=\"FALSE\"").Replace("/>", string.Format(defaultFormula, todaysDate));

   article.UpdateAndPushChanges(true);
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Using the [SharePoint Online Client Browser](https://spcb.codeplex.com/) we can see this change has been made:

[image]

When testing dont forget if you've already used the ArticleStartDate column in a Pages library SP can be funny about updating already used columns, give it a go in a new custom list or fresh site collection if in doubt.

Comment: This seems to resolve the issue. Acutally the `Sealed` property does not change, but the `=` in the formula, together with actually recreating the subweb using the `ArticleStartDate` got it working. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the key was to update field on web level and use `UpdateAndPushChanges(true)` to save it on list. Great answer!

Answer (score 2):

It does not work, because you're trying to set `DefaultValue` which expects literal value. What you want to set is `DefaultValueFormula`.

The problem is that this property is not exposed in CSOM.

I did manage to set default formula on field a while ago using this:

```
context.Load(field, f => f.SchemaXml);
context.ExecuteQuery();

var schema = field.SchemaXml;

var document = XDocument.Parse(schema);
var fieldElement = document.Element(XName.Get("Field"));

fieldElement.Elements(XName.Get("Default")).Remove();
fieldElement.Elements(XName.Get("DefaultFormula")).Remove();

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DefaultValue))
{
    var defaultElement = new XElement(XName.Get("Default"));
    defaultElement.Value = DefaultValue;
    fieldElement.Add(defaultElement);
}
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DefaultFormula))
{
    var formulaElement = new XElement(XName.Get("DefaultFormula"));
    formulaElement.Value = DefaultFormula;
    fieldElement.Add(formulaElement);
}

field.SchemaXml = document.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
field.Update();

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

**Edit:**
I've checked it with `ArticleStartDate` in O365 and was unsuccessful. Seems that this method won't work for fields with `Sealed='TRUE'`.

Comment: This actually looks supported too me (since you may create fields based on XML definition and there set `DefaultValueFormula`). I will give it a spin after converting it to PowerShell :)

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work on the `ArticleStartDate`field

Comment: Have you tried with any other field? It may be something specific to publishing. I'll check it in the evening.

Comment: I haven't have time trying on another field. Did you execute the code on the list column or the site column btw?

Comment: I've used it only on list columns.

Comment: It seems to not work at all on sealed columns

Comment: Checked again and it doesn't work for `ArticleStartDate`. Previously I assumed that missing `DefaultValueFormula` property in CSOM was the only problem, but it seems that you're right - won't work for sealed fields. Sorry.

Comment: I do appreciate your efforts :)

Answer (score -1):

Actually I think if field is read-only and sealed then we can’t write to it. 
So if you want to set value of sealed field then first you have to set its read-only and sealed property to false and then set default value.

```
$articleDateField.ReadOnlyField = $false
$articleDateField.Sealed = $false
$articleDateField.DefaultValue = "[Today]";
$articleDateField.Update()
$list.Update()
```

Comment: These properties (Sealed and ReadOnlyField) are not exposed in CSOM