# Change a field in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, column

I have identified a site column with incorrect properties. Specifically I need to change the RichText value from `FALSE` to `TRUE`. How can I do that?

I have tried to locate `Elements.xml` and edit that directly, but I cannot find it.

The site is a Sharepoint Public website, if that makes any difference. The tools I have is web browser, SharePoint Designer and SharePoint Online Client Browser.

Edit: As background: I try to accomplish the solution found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815053/rich-image-field-rendered-as-html-in-publishing-page-sharepoint

Comment: Is your site column is type of multi line of text?

Comment: Yes, a full HTML. Looks good as Site column, but incorrect when added to the list. I try to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815053/rich-image-field-rendered-as-html-in-publishing-page-sharepoint

Comment: Are you want to change  site column from rich text to plain text? then do it from sharepoint UI.

Comment: The accepted answer here basically helps you do it with PowerShell (replace the value in the SchemaXML property) http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171647/set-default-value-of-article-start-date-to-today-with-csom

Comment: Thanks. Is there any any other way? I believe using Powershell requires me to be admin for the domain? I have "full access" (although not owner) to the company's public website, but not our internal Sharepoint.